# Escaping special characters in Select statement SQL PHP

Tags: php, sql

How to escape column' special characters in SQL select statement.

I have that sql select statement and the column account_name has values that contains special characters, it gives me error as it doesn't escape those special characters.

```
select * from account where account_name ='$account_name'
```

Comment: Use prepared statements either in `PDO` or `mysqli`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use any of the MySQL extension commands, they are obsolete and not recommended anymore.

use PDO and prepared atatements.

http://php.net/pdo

```
$name = '$somethingHere';
$stmt = $db->prepare("Select * from account where account_name = :name");
$stmt->bindValue(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `mysql_real_escape_string($account_name)` function.